# using opengl in terminal application ( without glut/glew )

Tags: c++, c, xcode, macos, opengl

I am doing terminal application in xcode using c/c++, I don't want to use glut/glew. I'd like to create window and opengl context myself. Is it even possible?

Comment: Of course it is possible, but then you have a lot of grunt work ahead using xwindows.

Comment: Is there a reason that you don't want to use glut/glew?

Comment: I have custom frame system, but glut/glew uses 'glutmainloop'. Also I need to catch window instance, what is not available in glut/glew.

Comment: @Devolus: Actually, you would have to use Carbon (C / C++) or Cocoa (Obj-C) to create a window since this is OS X. And since Carbon is only partially exposed in 64-bit software in new versions of OS X, if you want this to work in a 64-bit application you might as well write your window management using Cocoa and NSOpenGL. It is certainly possible, I have maintained an OS X code path for my engine since OS X 10.2; but it gets messier and messier with each version of OS X that is released, and it is to the point where you have to mess around with ugly Objective C code just to target `x86_64`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing up things. GLEW is completely unrelated to window creation. It's there to load extension and modern OpenGL functions.

GLUT is not the only OpenGL windowing framework around. If you want to implement your own event loop have a look at GLFW, or SDL-2 or SFML. Other than that you've got a lot of work ahead (and doing it right is no easy task).